# Need to use lasers,mirrors and prisms for a project.How to make the light visible and presentable at the same time?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser

Alright so I really want to put some art into science for my project.project. I'm thinking of creating a beautiful image,preferably in air.I read about the visible lime-green lasers but i still want to be able to use other colors,and I need to make it visible.How can i make "fog" for it so that a pretty image is seen yet at the same time the inspectors won't be suffocating.Any ideas on how should I make it and what other things I can use to create pretty images?Please explain in details as I might not know some terms in optics.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typical shows use fog machines (some based on dry ice,others on inert compounds with short lifetimes). What's your budget?